Запуск Apache NiFi через Nginx
Всем привет! у меня есть NiFi с аутентификацией по OpenId через Keycloak. Все замечательно работает. Но появилась дополнительная задача : попадать в NiFi через Nginx.
Настроил все по документации NiFi, но ловлю постоянно ошибку :(

конфиг nginx:

    location /nifi {
        proxy_set_header X-ProxyScheme "https";
        proxy_set_header X-ProxyHost "proxy-host";
        proxy_set_header X-ProxyPort "443";
        proxy_set_header X-ProxyContextPath "/nifi";
        proxy_pass https://nifi-host.com:8443;
    }


nifi.properties

nifi.web.proxy.context.path=/
nifi.web.proxy.host=proxy-host:443

При первом запросе https://proxy-host:443/nifi честно отрабатывает и переходит на https://nifi-host.com:8443/nifi/. Следующий редирект должен привести на страницу https://nifi-host.com:8443/nifi-api/oauth2/authorization/consumer для получения токена, но редиректит в https://proxy-host:443/nifi/nifi-api/oauth2/authorization и браузер ругается, что мол 404 not found - оно и понятно, т.к. на тачке nginx нет keycloak. как заставить nginx далее подставлять не URL хоста прокси, а URL целевой тачки c NiFi для получения токена и дальнейшего общения с NiFi-библиотеками?
Заранее благодарен за любые идеи!
